# Dynamic ticks generation flot.js

Tags: flot

Why is it that when I put a dynamic array value in the ticks, It always starts with zero but when I specify a min and max in my flot options I get the correct output? any views on this?

I commented the one using min/max:

```
$(function () {

  var data = [ [
    [1301634000000, 315.71], //Apr 1, 2011
    [1302238800000, 209.21], //Apr 8, 2011
    [1302843600000, 420.36], //Apr 15
    [1303448400000, 189.86], //4/22
    [1304053200000, 314.93], //4/29
    [1304658000000, 279.71], //5/6
    [1305262800000, 313.34], //5/13
    [1305867600000, 114.67], //5/20
    [1306472400000, 315.58]  //5/27
  ] ];

  var ticks = [];
  var ticker=[315.71,209.21,420.36,189.86,314.93,279.71,313.34,114.67,315.58];
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    ticks.push(data[0][i][0]);
  }

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    xaxis: {
      mode: "time",
      ticks: ticks,
      timeformat: "%m/%d",
      min: (new Date(2011, 2, 31)).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(2011, 4, 31)).getTime()
    },
    yaxis: {
      ticks: ticker
      /*min: 114.67,
      max: 420.36*/
    },
    series: {
      lines: { show: true },
      points: { show: true }
    },
    grid: { 
      hoverable: true, 
      clickable: true 
    }
  });

});
```

and here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/A24Vt/110/)

I notice that in this example, it's not just formatted correctly and not properly scaled so entirely different from what Im asking but I applied the same thing in my prototype.

Comment: How about adding some code (maybe a fiddle) to demonstrate what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't understand your question, on your fiddle everything looks fine.  On the yaxis your decimal places are being removed by the `tickDecimals` option.  Here's an updated fiddle with more decimal places: http://jsfiddle.net/A24Vt/111/

Comment: @Mark please look at the y-axis notice how the axis points overlap each other?

Comment: You have 4 ticks very close together so sure they overlap. What else do you expect?

Comment: @Raidri But if you set a min/max it will look perfectly?

Comment: @a_miguel6687, no, you set a min/max, they still overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/A24Vt/112/

Comment: @Mark that's because you did not comment out the ticks parameter according to flot.js if you are going to use ticks its not practical to set a min and max parameter for your chart.